# Values inserted to my parameter suddenly vanished after the first expression

Tags: c

I have problems for my function, since after the first expression, the values inserted to my parameters (float x, float y) suddenly becomes 0.

I called this function with main (), the output for c = x/y works as expected. But for d = x - (y * c), it gives me an output of 0, I check where the problem is and it appears to be because of x and y since they both have 0 values for some reason

I have not finished my function for greatest common divisor, since I'm still stuck at this problem

'''

```
int gcd (float x, float y)
{

int c = x / y;                                  
printf ("This's your quotient: %d\n", c);
int d = x - ( y * c );                         // d = 0 since y, x = 0
printf ("This's your remainder: %d\n", d);     

printf ("c %d\n",c);                           // works normally
printf ("y %f\n",y);                           // y = 0
printf ("x: %f\n",x);                          // x = 0
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you call this function with, the output it gives, and why you think that output is wrong?

Comment: I called this function with main (), the output for c = x/y works as expected. But for d = x - (y * c), it gives me an output of 0, I check where the problem is and it appears to be because of x and y since they both have 0 values for some reason

Comment: Update question with code instead of a comment including the test data. This is not the greatest common denominator (gcd) algorithm.  Your gcd(17, 2) gives me 8, 1, 2.0, and 17.0 (not sure why you print x and y in reverse order not that it matters).

Comment: The only issues I see with the code is that you pass in float but does integer math.  `gcd(16.1,2)` returns 2, and 0 which is not correct (d should be 0.1).  If y is 0 you have a zero division, and if y is small then c may overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Allan, I'm still figuring out how to use stack overflow. And what your output seems to working fine. But for some reason when I insert in values, x y then becomes 0. For example my outputs for (25,7) are 4, 0 , 0.00 , 0.00

Comment: @iLikeTablesss that returns 3, 4, 3 7.0 and 25.0 for me.  Please update question with [mre] including a main() that calls your function.  My guess, you are not compiling your program, and looking at output from an old program.

Comment: Change x and y to int (or unsigned) and your values are cast accordingly when you call the function.  Much clearer.

Comment: @AllanWind, since I want to remove everything after the decimal, the solution I came up with is to cast from float to int. Are there other ways to do this? For example for 15/7, I want 2 rather than 2.14

Comment: cast is fine, but if you change the type of x and y to unsigned, the cast happens when you call the function instead of inside your gcd function.  Also, change the return type to void or return something.

Comment: Allan thanks so much for all the the help :) The problem wasn't in the function as you said but it was in the main(). I have applied all the changes you told me such as unsigned and void. Again thanks so much mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example code that fixes the issues I noticed and changing the signature to separate calculations from output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quotient_reminder(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned *q, unsigned *r) {
    if(y == 0) return;
    *q = x / y;
    *r = x - (y * *q); // d = 0 since y, x = 0
}

int main() {
    unsigned q, r;
    quotient_reminder(25.0, 7.1, &q, &r);
    printf ("This's your quotient: %u\n", q);
    printf ("This's your remainder: %u\n", r);
}
```

and it will return:

```
This's your quotient: 3
This's your remainder: 4
```